# Open different activity when click on marker(multiple marker)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragments

I wanted to open new activity of map when I click on marker. I have created multiple marker but in this code I am just getting the title name form it.

For example there are 7 marker locations, if I press on any marker new activity opens and some data should be there and so if I click on another marker another activity opens with some content on it.

But it should open and show some details regarding the location. You can just guide me by only two activities after that I will be able to do the rest.

**Location1Fragment.java**

```java
package com.example.ncaputtarakhand;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Location1Fragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Location1Fragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> arrayList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    LatLng Tasmorth = new LatLng(-31.083332, 150.916672);
    LatLng NewCast = new LatLng(-32.916668, 151.750000);
    LatLng Brisbane = new LatLng(-27.470125, 153.021072);
    LatLng Dubbo = new LatLng(-32.256943, 148.601105);

    //for creating name for markers
    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();


    public Location1Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Location1Fragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Location1Fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Location1Fragment fragment = new Location1Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        arrayList.add(sydney);
        arrayList.add(Tasmorth);
        arrayList.add(NewCast);
        arrayList.add(Brisbane);
        arrayList.add(Dubbo);
        title.add("Sydney");
        title.add("Tasmorth");
        title.add("NewCast");
        title.add("Brisbane");
        title.add("Dubbo");
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location1, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
        for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<title.size();j++)
            {
                //this loop for setting title
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arrayList.get(i)).title(String.valueOf(title.get(j))));
            }

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arrayList.get(i)));
        }
        //we add onclick listener
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String markertitle= marker.getTitle();

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("title",markertitle);
                startActivity(i);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your map OnMarkerClickListerner, just check your marker position match with your place location

```
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    String markertitle= marker.getTitle();
                    if (marker.getPosition() == Tasmorth){
                        //launch activity here
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

You should store your marker to a list to easy compare location.

Comment: Actually i am starting activity as you shown but i am getting only title not opening any activity